# Calling an Excel user defined function from Python always returns None

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to get the return value from an Excel function that i called from a python.
I always get a `None` value.

Here is the excel function :

```
Public Function GetString()
    GetString = "aa"
End Function
```

And Here is the call :

`xlApp.Run('ThisWorkbook.GetString')`

Returned :`None`

I have no problem getting in the specified function since I tried to modify a cell value from it and it worked.

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how you assigned your variable `xlApp`.
Assuming code like

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp = xlApp.Application
```

consider:

1. You have to assign the result to a variable, as in

   `myStr = xlApp.Run('ThisWorkbook.GetString')`
2. You seem to have placed the user defined function in `ThisWorkbook`, in the Excel file. Unless this is intentional, open the Excel file, insert a Module in the Visual Basic Editor, and move there your Function. Modify your call from Python accordingly.
3. You may want to define the function as

   `Public Function GetString() as String`

See
[How to call Excel VBA functions and subs using Python win32com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732340/how-to-call-excel-vba-functions-and-subs-using-python-win32com)

Comment: I forgot the return type but I don't get why it wouldn't work from the workbook but on a module.

Comment: I was not sure if that would make a difference. At the least, it is a matter of good coding practice (which would not explain your second question). I have seen a couple of strange things when moving code this way, so I though it might have been an additional factor in you problem.