# Receive Result from VBA script via Python

Tags: vba, python-2.7, win32com

TLDR: I want to **receive the result**(to python) from a vba function that I triggered via python. I am **able** to trigger the vba function.

I am able to **trigger** a vba function via python. Now, I want to receive the **result** of that vba function back in that **same** python program (the one that called the vba function). How do I do it?

Is it even possible?

Currently I am triggering my vba via this function:

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
result = xl.Application.Run("my_vba_function_name", param1)
```

The reason why I want to **trigger a vba function** rather that **modifying the excel file directly via python** is that I want to be able to open and view/edit the file via **microsoft excel** at the **same time**.

Thanks

EDIT: I got the result from the other post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Excel VBA functions and subs using Python win32com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732340/how-to-call-excel-vba-functions-and-subs-using-python-win32com)

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane I do not think this is a duplication. I am able to call VBA functions. I just want to find out is there a way to get some form of result from them.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Ah I see! Thanks!